# issue with apex_application_temp_files

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a problem, in my ORACLE APEX app, I want to have file uploading mechanism that send uploaded .zip file as parameter to some function (that function works well, I tested it by manual feeding from DB). Problem is, when I try to select uploaded file from "apex_application_temp_files" in a process it throws exception "NO DATA FOUND", but when I add report to app where I select ID and FILENAMES I see that file...any idea why this is happen?
I am sorry if this is some trivial issue, but I am pretty new in APEX developing.

The process:

```
declare
    l_blob blob;
begin
    SELECT blob_content
      INTO l_blob
      FROM apex_application_temp_files
      WHERE NAME = :P6_FILE;
    --INSTANTLY SET :G_TEST_ID FOR REPORTS
    :G_TEST_ID := file_management.unwrap_zip(ab_zipped_blob => l_blob);
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps log the value and see if it's actually set to the filename - e.g. add `apex_debug.message(:P6_FILE);` in there.

Comment: Which apex version are you on?

Comment: Apex version is 5.0.2.00.07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select on column `NAME` instead of `FILENAME`. The former is the unique identifier (looks like `series_of_numbers\the_filename`) and is what the file browse item will contain, while the latter is without the prefix.

---

Look, you'll have to provide more information from your end. I've created a really simple page to try this (apex.oracle.com).

`P2_FILE` is a file-browse item.

- Storage Type: Table APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES
- Purge File at: End of Session

I've created an on-submit process which does nothing more than list some things in the debug output.

```
declare
    l_blob blob;
begin 
  for r in (select * from apex_application_temp_files)
  loop
    apex_debug.message('name: %s - filename: %s', r.name, r.filename);
  end loop;

  apex_debug.message('P2_FILE: %s', :P2_FILE);

    SELECT blob_content
      INTO l_blob
      FROM apex_application_temp_files
      WHERE name = :P2_FILE;

  apex_debug.message('blob length: %s', dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob));
end;
```

So I run the page, enable debug, select a file and hit submit. All works. Check the debug log (accept):

```
name: 39044609744029199463/README (2).md - filename: README (2).md
name: 39044529927808550681/README (1).md - filename: README (1).md
name: 39044569042020557797/README.md - filename: README.md
P2_FILE: 39044609744029199463/README (2).md
blob length: 1884
```

So: what's different at your end? Have you done as suggested by Jeffrey and run a debug of the page? What is your "purge" set as? Are you sure the no-data-found occurs on select of the blob and not in your procedure - have you commented out your procedure call yet?

Comment: Thanks, I already found that out, but still the same result NO_DATA_FOUND

Comment: @Silverrook First, try basic, like my code above. Nothing spectacular, just debug things. Provide some more details on your setup. Try things out. I don't think we can help any further without more information.

Comment: @Tom, is it possible to get item name from name column on apex_application_temp_files ? for instance, can we know what was the name (or label) of the item that created 39044609744029199463/README (2).md ?