# Oracle APEX: File not loading into apex_application_temp_files

Tags: file-upload, oracle-apex

I have an application in APEX (Oracle Application Express 5.0.0.00.31) and I would like to make the file upload on one page. This is what I currently have:

[image]

This is a simple file browser item and a button with action: "Submit page".

My File browser according to new features of APEX 5 should store it's uploaded files (once the page is submitted) in the table `apex_application_temp_files` and purge them at the end of session, but nothing is ever there.

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

This is what I have in the `apex_application_temp_files` just after the upload:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033701/issue-with-apex-application-temp-files ?

Comment: Hi, I tried that and this is not the case, I think I'm doing something wrong with my file browser item because I get the error: No data found. My file is basically never uploaded for some reason

Comment: @Tom to be exact, the debug procedure you provided returns this: `"AJAX call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for Execute PL/SQL Code."`

Comment: Why "AJAX call"? Have you put this code in a dynamic action, and not in an on-submit process?

Comment: Hi sorry about that, my bad. So I created "After submit" process (In choosing `Point` there was no on-submit option) and the error is the same: `1 error has occurred ORA-01403: no data found`

Comment: Okay: so just do the loop over the table and view the debug. Are there liens in there (there should be). Also, keep in mind that selecting on the view from sql developer may simply not work because of built-in restrictions in those views and which may only work within an active apex session! Furthermore, it helps when you just share your code (if there's any). Just uploading the file and then checking in an sql-dev session is not correct.

Comment: @Tom Thanks a lot! I had no idead about those restrictions! The files I uploaded are indeed there.

Comment: So following the instruction from the linked answer, can you perform a select on the file by using `NAME = :YOUR_FILE_BROWSE_ITEM`? When doing the loop in the debug, you should see the names there. Doing a debug output of the file input item should allow you to verifiy names and columns.

Comment: Yes, I have all the files I added in this session. Now I'm off to deal with the blob content, thanks for sharing your knowledge ;)

Comment: @Tom is there a way to access the uploaded files outside the session? I have the xlsx file in the blob and I'd like to see how does it look like before I start dealing with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - what's your intention? You upload the file and then what should happen with it? The purpose of the temp-files table is to take the uploaded file(s) and then move them to their final destination, usually a "real" table (which has blob column(s)).

Comment: I'm not sure if you know the `as_read_xlsx` - this is a function for reading xlsx file. I wanted to do this on my blob: `select * from table( as_read_xlsx.read( l_blob ) );` to see what is in there but for that I would have to access it from sql developer somehow. My idea was to copy the blob to some temp table but then I had this error in sql developer: `oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.incrementTempLobReferenceCount([B)V`

Comment: upload the file. Move the blob to a real table (NOT global temporary). Then access it from sqldeveloper. Just do it like that for your own sanity. Afterwards, if requiring a temp table for apex, you will need to use apex collections.

Comment: As I told you I did do that, I moved to it to newly created table that contain only id, name and blob columns and for some reason i can do `select * from table_temp;` from apex sql workshop but not from sql developer. Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122172/discussion-between-tom-and-aleksander-lipka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested here: [issue with apex_application_temp_files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033701/issue-with-apex-application-temp-files)

Use some debug as a sanity check.

Don't try to query the view from sqldeveloper, it won't give you the results you require as it won't work without some contexts set (or without a session). Since sqldev. This is why at first looping over the files in the view helps you most, and just crossref it with the value from the file-item. You can then set up the `select into` statement, debug that, and if working go from there.

Comment: This was a very important information! I spent hours trying to figure out what's wrong.